# Wiring 5V sensors to Beaglebone Black

Tags: beagle-bone

Is there a "cape" to make wiring sensors into a Beaglebone Black easier?

Whenever I read some guide for wiring a sensor into the Beaglebone (like [this one](http://beagleboard.org/support/BoneScript/Ultrasonic_Sensor/)) it always recommends attaching wires directly to GND, +V and signal pins, which is horribly messy and unmaintainable. Even for small projects, you end up having several wires connected to the same GND/5V+ pins, so if you need to replace or repair something, you end up disrupting the wiring for every other component in your project.

Most Arduino guides assume this bad practice too, but at least I've found various ["GVS" shields](http://sandboxelectronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/SLD-000010.main_-399x399.jpg) to help organize groups of GND/5V/Signal pins so I can attach individual sensor cables.

Is there anything similar for the Beaglebone? I can't find anything appropriate Googling "breakout" or "IO" cape. I could only find one [GVS cape](http://beagleboard.org/project/BBB-GVS/), but it's less than ideal, since it only exposes 5 5V GPIO pins, and everything else it exposes as 3.3V or 1.8V which are incompatible with most peripherals.

Comment: I usually connect the GND and the +5/+3.3 to an external clamp, which i can extend like I want. You only have to regard the maximum current, so you do not destroy anything on the beaglebone.

Comment: This is essentially just some male and female headers. Ever thought of soldering your own?